# How to generate variable names in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

How do you put an int, that changes for each for/while-loop, at the end of a variable name.

I would like to generate about 40 different sprite-variables, each with a different number.

Is there a basic method for doing this?

Comment: You surely could use [arrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html), no? It's a great way to keep track of many objects, because it enables you to do operations on each element if you so need, without having to name all 40 (or who-knows-many) variables.

Comment: Yeah, the number actually refer to rows in an array.

Answer (score -1):

This would do what you are asking:

```
// on Flash's main timeline
for(var i:int = 0; i < 40; i++){
    this["sprite" + i] = new Sprite();
}
```

You'd end up with properties on the main timeline of `sprite0`, `sprite1`, `sprite2`, ...`sprite39`. (Note that this code example doesn't actually add the sprites, and it doesn't assign a `name` to them, so `getChildByName("sprite0")` would not work for example.)

However, I should say a few things about this.

First, assigning new properties like this only works on "dynamic" object instances. `MovieClip` is dynamic, which is why placing the code on the main timeline and using `this` should work (because the main timeline is a `MovieClip`, unless you specify otherwise with a document class). Generic `Objects` and `Arrays` are also dynamic, because they are meant to be generic data containers. However, almost nothing else in AS3 is dynamic, including other display object classes and any class you create, [unless you explicitly declare it as `dynamic`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html). For instance, if you tried to assign a property to a `Sprite` you get a runtime error:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s["hello"] = "goodbye";
```

Throws:

> ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property hello on flash.display.Sprite.

And if you try to access "hello" as a property using dot syntax, it won't even compile:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.hello = "goodbye";
```

Fails to compile with:

> 1119: Access of possibly undefined property hello through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite.

This default non-dynamic (aka "sealed") behavior of classes should be an indicator that there's usually a better way than to assign new properties to display objects (and other random stuff) at runtime. `MovieClips` are likely only dynamic to accommodate old patterns established by Flash (that's my guess).

So what you can do is use an `Array`:

```
var sprites:Array = [];
for(var i:int = 0; i < 40; i++){
    sprites.push(new Sprite());
}
```

What this code will give you is an array called `sprites` which has 40 indices, each referencing a different sprite. (Again this code doesn't do anything useful with the `Sprites`.) You can get a reference to a sprite by index like this:

```
var sprite:Sprite = sprites[0];
// do whatever you want with 'sprite'
```

Hope that helps.